# I installed TeXLive 2020, but when I try to latex a file with TexShop, it doesn't do anything

Tags: texshop

Correct location for tex live: /usr/local/texlive/2020
Correct location for TexShop:  /applications/TeX

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you on a MacOS system? If so, how did you install TeXLive? By downloading and running the MacTeX self-installer? By some other method? Please be specific.